# Retrieve a basic data with Youtube API

Tags: php, curl, youtube, youtube-api

I don't know really how to use Youtube API.. until today I retrieve data from Youtube with cUrl.

I fount out the API of Youtube and I really consider to start using with the API.
The data I need is really basic, just the name and the description of the video.. If I will use the api, will it be fast then cUrl?

Can you bring me a code to retrieve just the name and the description of the Youtube video by url or id?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Developer's Guide: Data API Protocol – Retrieving Data for a Single Video
To retrieve information about a single video, you can send a GET request to the following URL. (You need to replace the text videoid with the video's actual video ID.)
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/videoid?v=2
or "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[id]?fields=title"
More info at http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries.html

hopefully it helps :)